# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING Chrome Root page load

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website on a lamp stack with little to no extra configuration other than `FallbackResource /index.php` present in my root .htaccess

When I load the root page (localhost ) in Chrome I receive

`GET http://192.168.163.171/ net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING        VM110:1`

in the chrome console after about 10 seconds. If I attempt to follow the link at VM110:1 it takes me to the top of my inline Javascript.

### More information / What I've tried

- This does NOT occur on any other page but root
- There are no 404's in the access log nor any other abnormal codes
- There are no errors appearing in the apache error log.
- The error does not occur in the latest version of IE or Firefox.
- It caused a problem in both my local environment and hosted. The latter has absolutely no config changes and I expect to be a near default install.
- When I remove the `FallbackResource` directive my page loads fine without the error

In index.php the root is treated no different than any other page.

This would all be a non-issue because everything loads properly BUT it prevents javascript relying on a finished page load from working.

Any further ideas on what is causing the problem or new things I can try? I've considered moving to just using mod_rewrite but this is much simpler.

Comment: Hi i have the same problem, did u find out?

Comment: No sorry, I decided it wasn't a blocking issue and pretty much just ignored it.

Comment: I think it's something to do with Chrome, but unsure. Do you have adblock? If so, turn it off and try.

Comment: Yes it's a Chrome only issue. No it was a clean install of Chrome.

Comment: Having the same problem. It's preventing some javascript from running properly on document load. It's also cause by the `FallbackResource`. Really annoying!

Comment: I am experiencing the same. I didn't change anything on the server's config nor chrome.

Comment: I have also faced the same issue but I am working on Java application with Tomcat 7. As read in the comments and the solution too, my issue also comes only in Chrome. Any guidance would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally found the answer while working on another site:

Before `FallbackResource` directive be sure to add a `DirectoryIndex` directive with the same file. Haven't had time to research why but it fixed my issue. I blame it on a Chrome bug or possibly Chrome being super picky because no other major browser has an issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. It was a big help.

Comment: So, does anyone know why or how this might work?  Is the bad behavior on Apache's side, or is it on Chrome's side?

Comment: My guess is that it's bad behaviour on Apache's side but the administrator's fault for configuring the directives wrong. Most likely the other browsers have an issue with it too, but they ignore it whereas Chrome actually says something and breaks.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks because it's been like that for weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by removing the following lines from my `php5filter.conf` file in the Apache configuration:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetInputFilter PHP
    SetOutputFilter PHP
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I upgraded from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 (debian 6) and had to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Blaine's answer (as I can't yet comment):

I believe this is an Apache configuration issue, not specific to Chrome.

I recently experienced this issue, and noted the following effects in various clients, again only with the home page:

- Chrome, as stated, displayed the `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` error, but also didn't display the page correctly. The page continued to "load" for another 5 seconds even after all the content was visible.
- A simple CURL request outputted the error `curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`. The full HTML appeared, followed by the error after a delay.
- Firefox and IE initially displayed the page incorrectly, as with Chrome, and again had the ~5 second additional loading time. However, after this period, the page suddenly reformatted itself correctly. No errors were seen in the respective developer consoles.

The solution to set the `DirectoryIndex` to the same location as `FallbackResource` resolved this for all clients.

**Edit:** An alternative if using mod_rewrite is to use something like `RewriteRule ^$ index.php` which will avoid affecting all subdirectories.

I don't know whether this is expected behaviour of Apache or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my json response '\n' causing the issue. So after removing it, issue has been solved.