# FallbackResource causes net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-chrome

When I use a `.htaccess` that contains just this line:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

I get this error on Chrome only:

```
 net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

The error appears only when access the root directory where the `.htaccess` is located.

IE, if `.htacess` is in `www.mysite.org/admin` then the error only appears when I type that exact URL in the nav bar.

If I go to `www.mysite.org/admin/index.php` or `www.mysite.org/admin/some-user-friendly-url` there is no error.

The error is really annoying as it delays the page load by several seconds and makes the page fail to execute some JavaScript that should happen on page load.

Like many others with this error, it only happens in Chrome. Solutions from other posts were of no help in my particular case.

Comment: Maybe similar to this ? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506856/err-incomplete-chunked-encoding-chrome-root-page-load

Answer (score 7):

Add `DirectoryIndex` directive to `.htaccess` file before `FallbackResource`. This fixed the problem for me.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```